# func is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I'm trying to create a simple webpage using Flask, I'm trying to capture the text written in a textfield in a javascript variable and then display it on console, when the user presses a button.

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/main.js')}}"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="txtWord" name="search" placeholder="Search..." >
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="# Result..." id="inputNumResults">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="buttonSearch" onclick="getText()">Search for words</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getText() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('txtWord').innerHTML;
    console.log(txt);
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? What error?

Comment: Apparently my function is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: getText is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: What does the output of `src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/main.js')}}"` look like?

Comment: Since I'm using flask, all sources must be that way, it isn't a 404 error, because flask can find my file, the output of the file should be whatever I put in the textfield "txtWord"

Comment: So what does `console.log(txt)` outputs on your console?,

Comment: Try instead `var txt = document.getElementById('txtWord').val();`

Comment: @PCalle100 What's wrong with my answer? It's working perfectly fine...

Comment: @Badacadabra I didn't downvote it. I just haven't tested it yet

Comment: @PCalle100 You know, you can just click on "Run code snippet" to test it... ;)

Comment: @PCalle100 where are You putting this script tag?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ovtkmnmn/3/ Here is working solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is working solution

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" id="txtWord" name="search" placeholder="Search..." >
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="# Result..." id="inputNumResults">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="buttonSearch" onclick="gt()">Search for words</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function gt() {
        var txt = document.getElementById("txtWord").value;
        alert(txt);
    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ovtkmnmn/3/

I believe in Your case the problem is about order of loading this js file.

Always check what console displays, when I used "On load" load type it clearly returned an error that the function is not defined

Comment: what if I created this `button` `<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="buttonSearch" onclick="gt()">Search for words</button>` using jqeury

it seem not to be working

Answer (score 3):

You should simply **clear your browser's cache**. A full browser's cache can cause such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function () {
  function getText() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('txtWord').value;
    console.log(txt);
  }

  document.getElementById('buttonSearch').addEventListener('click', getText, true);
})();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" id="txtWord" name="search" placeholder="Search..." >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="# Result..." id="inputNumResults">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="buttonSearch">Search for words</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The listener needs to be after the `getText()` function. The listener can't call something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You should add a description to why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using **jQuery** until I figure out that I declared the function inside the $(document).ready() method :

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      function name(){}  // not working
    }
```